# How to remove a bunch of files without a certain suffix

Tags: linux, bash

I'm on Linux, using Bash.

I need to remove all files *without* a certain suffix, for example "dist". I know there are some tricks to do it, rather than removing all the unwanted files one by one.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following to list all the files that would be removed (just to be sure):

```
find /path/to/directory -mindepth 1 ! -name "*dist"
```

Add `-type f` if you only want to delete regular files, not symbolic links or directories.

---

Run the command with additional `-delete` argument at the end to remove them.

Comment: @slhck Thanks, don't know what I was thinking (probably not much)

Answer (score 2):

If you have extended globbing enabled, you can try:

```
rm !(*.dist)
```

Note: if you have directories without the .dist extension, this will will try and delete them too, but will fail.

To turn on extended globbing use: `shopt -s extglob`